# In R, how does plot() work for fb prophet models?

Tags: r, facebook, plot

[Facebook's Prophet](https://research.fb.com/prophet-forecasting-at-scale/) in R (there's also a Python version) is used to generate time series forecasts.

A model m is created by:

```
m <- prophet(df)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
plot(m, forecast)
```

Which returns a very nicely formatted graph, like:

[image]

I would like to add other metrics to the graph, besides those are part of **m** and **forecast**, for example to add the result of a forecast generated by another forecasting method, etc...

But when I try something like:

`plot(m,forecast, arima_model)`

I get an error:

```
 Error in uncertainty && exists("yhat_lower", where = df) : 
 invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

So how can I add other data to the prophet model plot?

Additionally, where is the cool formatting (grey background with grid, well formatted dates, uncertainties with color schemes, etc...) coming from?

I though **plot()** might be picking up arguments from **m**, but when I check **m** is seems to be a regular data frame. I can't see anything that would indicate arguments for formatting a plot.

```
names(m)

[1] "growth"                  "changepoints"            "n.changepoints"         
[4] "yearly.seasonality"      "weekly.seasonality"      "daily.seasonality"      
[7] "holidays"                "seasonality.prior.scale" "changepoint.prior.scale"
[10] "holidays.prior.scale"    "mcmc.samples"           "interval.width"         
[13] "uncertainty.samples"     "specified.changepoints"  "start"                  
[16] "y.scale"                 "logistic.floor"          "t.scale"                
[19] "changepoints.t"          "seasonalities"          "extra_regressors"       
[22] "stan.fit"                "params"                  "history"                
[25] "history.dates"          

typeof(m)
[1] "list"
```

Where is *plot()* getting all there formatting from ? And how can add additional I data to plot?

Comment: It uses `ggplot2`. If you type `plot.prophet` in the console you can see the complete code. You should be able to modify it like any ggplot.

Comment: Gregor is right, you need ggplot2. Here is a link to some resources: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error is you are giving three arguments to a plot which takes two arguments. If you want to compute the moving average (armia_model) and compare it to what you plotted previously, you could do something like this:

```
library(prophet)
library(ggplot2)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- fread("pm.csv") # Payton Manning's Yearly Yardage

m <- prophet(df)

future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)

forecast <- predict(m, future)

plot(m, forecast) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Data") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  ggtitle("Learning How to Use Prophet")
```

[Click for Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K12oP.png)

Now, lets calculate the moving average (7 day) and then use prophet to analyze the results

```
arma <- data.frame(df$ds, ma(df$y, order = 7))

colnames(arma) <- c("ds", "tsma_order") 

arma_df_for_prophet <- inner_join(df, arma, by = "ds") %>% 
    filter(tsma_order != is.na(tsma_order))

m_arma <- prophet(arma_df_for_prophet)

future_arma <- make_future_dataframe(m_arma, periods = 365)

forecast_arma <- predict(m_arma, future_arma)

plot(m_arma, forecast_arma)
```

[Plot for Moving Average, Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPqLP.png)

If you type m or forecast in the console it will show you all the elements of each dataframe. Same thing goes for m_arma and forecast_arma.

You can find the full CRAN for prophet [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf), which you should read to understand how the package works. Hope this helps answer your question.